# Angular i18n not supporting all locales in angular.json

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-localize, angularbuild

My angular application  I want to support languages french(Canada), french(France) and US english. This is my angular.json file i18n code.

```
"i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en",
        "locales": {
          "fr-CA": "src/locale/messages.fr-CA.xlf",
          "fr-FR": "src/locale/messages.fr-FR.xlf"
        }
      }
```

Upon Building application (npm run build) I see  a message **Locale data for 'fr-FR' cannot be found.  Using locale data for 'fr'.**

1. Does this mean fr-FR is not allowed in angular.json, as it is not in ISO-639 list.
2. Should I use `"fr": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf"`  instead of fr-FR. Then should I match if the user in France (fr-FR locale) load code from  fr in dist folder.
3. If '2' is wrong ignore the warning and as build producing fr-Fr specific application in dist folder use that.
4. If  '2' is correct does that apply for all locales say use ***en*** for 'en-GB','en-CA'...

I know there is something like registerLocaleData for displaying of dates and currency.

```
registerLocaleData(localeFr); 

providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR'},
  ]
```

I went over documentation few times https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview. I know I am missing something.